# infinite ajax scroll demo issue on chrome

Tags: infinite-scroll

I'm trying to test the infinite scrolling demo at the following url https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll/blob/master/demo/page1.html

I just did a copy and paste and the demo works on safari (mac) and not on chrome ver. 32.0.1700.102 (mac). Do I forgot something? Live example at http://twitstat.it/page1.html

Answer (score 0):

A new version (v2.0) of the plugin is available and a demo is available here: http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/examples/basic.html